# How to directly inject packets to another module in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++

My compound module is multiple layers as show in the attached figure.
[image]

Here Layer2 has a `cPacketQueue` buffer and I want the Layer1 module to directly insert packets into this `cPacketQueue` of Layer2. Layer1 and Layer2 gates are connected unidirecttionally as show in the figure.

```
Layer1Gate --> Layer2Gate
```

**UPDATED:**

`Layer 1` creates Packets with different priorities `(0-7)` and injects to `8` different `cPacketQueues` in `Layer2` named as `priorityBuffers[i]`, (i is the index).

The `Layer2` then sends self messages in `intervals of 10ns` to poll all these buffers in each `iteration` and `send` the packets.

This is all I am doing now. It works fine. But I know 10ns polling is definitely not an efficient way to do this and achieve QoS. So requesting for a better alternative.

Comment: It looks like the actual question you want to ask is missing! It sounds to me as though you're looking for [this](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec161) part of the manual, and that you want a simple reception system where you just move the event from the gate to the queue with [cPacketQueue.insert](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classcPacketQueue.html#a9ecf782bfd8f5c5f3749a945d040bafd).

Comment: @user3243499: What do you mean "directly"? If you define channel without delay between `Layer1` and `Layer2`, then you can use `send()` method and a packet from `Layer1` will be received in `Layer2` without any delay (i.e. at the same moment, when it was sent). And in `handleMessage()` of `Layer2` you should cast received message into `cPacket` object and then insert to your queue, for example: `cPacket *packet = check_and_cast<cPacket *> (msg); yourqueue->insert(packet); `

Comment: @JerzyD. Yes, it will get delivered without any delay. But the problem is I have multiple buffers in Layer2 to support QoS (Priorities using multiple buffers). And so I need to schedule a self message timer in Layer 2. Now if I set the polling interval for this buffers to very small say, 6ns using `scheduleAt()` then the simulation becomes very slow and packets are seen waiting at the end of the links without actually getting delivering the packet to the destination module.

Comment: @user3243499: If I understood correctly: `Layer1` wants to send a packet to `Layer2` and this packet should be inserted to a specific queue. And `Layer1` knows which queue should be used for particular packet, doesn't it? To achieve that you **do not need selfmessages**. In `OMNeT++` there is `ControlInfo` mechanism, which allows one to add some piece of information into a packet. I propose: in `Layer1` adding a `ControlInfo` object with number (name) of desired queue to the packet and send this packet through `Layer2`.Then `Layer2` will check this `ControlInfo` object and choose proper queue.

Comment: @user3243499: If you extend your question with number of queues or names of these queues, I will give you a sample code for using `ControlInfo` in my answer.

Comment: @JerzyD. Updated. Please suggest an alternative and proper way of achieving that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding a `ControlInfo` object with priority to every packet from `Layer1`, send the packet using `send()` command, then checking `ControlInfo` of received packet in `Layer2`, and insert the packet into a specific queue. 
Firstly, one should define a class for `ControlInfo`, for example in `common.h`:

```
// common.h
class PriorityControlInfo : public cObject {
public:
    int priority;
};
```

Then in C++ code of `Layer1` simple module:

```
#include "common.h"
// ...
// in the method where packet is created
cPacket * packet = new cPacket();
PriorityControlInfo * info = new PriorityControlInfo();
info->priority = 2;  // 2 is desired queue number
packet->setControlInfo(info);
send (packet, "out");
```

And finally in `Layer2`:

```
#include "common.h"
// ...
void Layer2::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
    cPacket *packet = dynamic_cast<cPacket *>(msg);
    if (packet) {
        cObject * ci = packet->removeControlInfo();
        if (ci) {
            PriorityControlInfo * info = check_and_cast<PriorityControlInfo*>(ci);
            int queue = info->priority;
            EV << "Received packet to " << static_cast<int> (queue) << " queue.\n";
            priorityBuffers[queue].insert(packet);
            EV << priorityBuffers[queue].info() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

According to using of self messages: I do not understand clearly what is your intention.

1. Does `Layer2` should send a packet *immediately* after receiving it? If yes why do you use a buffer? In that situation instead of inserting a packet to a buffer, `Layer2` should just send it to the `Layer3`.
2. Does `Layer2` should do something else after receiving a packet and inserting it in a buffer? If yes, just call this action (function) in the above `handleMessage()`.

In the both above variants there is no need to use self messages.

Comment: Thanks Jerzy. Now I got the idea. Jerzy, regarding the self messages, I just want to simulate priorities of packets. For example, priority 7 packets should be sent before priority 6 which in turn should be sent before priority 5 packets and so on. Please suggest how to achieve this without using `self messages` at all.

Comment: The solution depends on `Layer3` transmission procedure. There are at least two possibilities: **1.** `Layer3` sends to `Layer2` a request, when `Layer3` wants to send a frame (packet). Immediately after receiving this request `Layer2` checks whether it has any packet in priorityBuffers[7], if yes it takes this packet and send to `Layer3`. If not - `Layer2` checks priorityBuffers[6] etc. In this way `Layer2` always is waiting for request from `Layer3`. The request may be modelled as a usual `cMessage` object.

Comment: **2.** `Layer2` knows that it has to send to `Layer3` some number of packets every a period of time (e.g. 1ms). In that situation using of self messages is necessary. Each time after receiving a self message `Layer2` has to check whether it has any packet in `priorityBuffers[7]`. If yes it takes this packet and sends to Layer3. If not - `Layer2` checks `priorityBuffers[6]` etc. Note that in this way period of triggering selfmessage depends on concept of transmission in `Layer3`. I assume, that `Layer3` is able to send further limited amount of bytes, and this period reflects this restriction.